# Why a <div> don't resize to wrap <a> padding, if <a> 'display' is not declared as 'inline-block'

Tags: html, css

I made a simple menu header, but if the `<a>` tag is not a `inline-block`, the `<div>` wraps only the content size, and not the padding... I just need to know why this happen, and if there is another way of making the `<div>` tag wraps the whole content including the padding . Here is the code:

**.html** :

```
<div class="menu">
  <a class="menu-item" href="#">Menu 1</a>
  <a class="menu-item" href="#">Menu 2</a>
  <a class="menu-item" href="#">Menu 3</a>
</div>
```

**.css:**

```
.menu {
    background-color: lightsalmon;
}

/* menu item */
.menu .menu-item {
    /* sizing */
    display: inline-block; /* IF REMOVED, THE MENU <div> WILL IGNORE THE <a>PADDING */
    padding: 16px;
    min-width: 64px;

    /* text decorating */
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.menu .menu-item:hover {
    background-color: salmon;
}
```

Thank you for any help !

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the height of your main , that's why it's not showing the `menu-item` correctly.

links by default uses `display: inline` , which does not grow automaticly.

Try to add : `display:flex;` to your menu class ( when you add this your `menu` will take the needed `height` to display the `menu-items` correctly ): https://codepen.io/Aypro18/pen/PoPGwoq

```css
.menu {
    background-color: lightsalmon;
  display:flex;
}

/* menu item */
.menu .menu-item {
    /* sizing */
    padding: 16px;
    min-width: 64px;

    /* text decorating */
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.menu .menu-item:hover {
    background-color: salmon;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <a class="menu-item" href="#">Menu 1</a>
  <a class="menu-item" href="#">Menu 2</a>
  <a class="menu-item" href="#">Menu 3</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:flex;` in your main css , and drop that `display: inline-block;` from your `menu-item`.

Answer (score -1):

This happens because `<a>` elements are `display: inline`.

Inline elements, unlike `block`, `inline-block`, `flex` and `inline-flex` don't grow in `height`. If you try to use`height: 100px`, you will see an inline element will not grow in height.

Once the `<a>` element is one of the above mentioned displays, however, it enables it to gain height, and therefore height from padding.